# Error while building kotlin app having jetpack compose, dagger and room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, kapt

I have the same project running on two machines. On one machine everything is working fine but on the other machine it gives the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x4bd6cb74) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x4bd6cb74
```

Below is my build.gradle (app-level)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pranaydas.smartqr"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.1'

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
}
```

Below is my build.gradle (project-level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.2'
        accompanist_version = '0.24.9-beta'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried deleting the .gradle folder, gradlew and gradlew.bat files but still it gives me the same error. This happens only for this project. My other projects are working fine on both the machines.

I suspect there's something to do with the Room Database.

**UPDATE: **
Replacing 'kapt' with 'annotationProcessor' fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

So I changed all instances of 'kapt' from my dependencies to 'annotationProcessor'